# php regex replace substring

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to detect a url with php regex and replace all the `&amp` that is has with just `&`. I had run `htmlspecialchars` in all my input data but i want urls to readable. I did that which obviously doesnt work because the replace part is wrong.

```
preg_replace('!(http(s)?://((\S)|(&amp))*)!m', '&', $message);
```

Basically i want all the string to remain the same but change the &amp when it occurs within an url.I was thinking to use `preg_match_all` but if the values of the array are not passed by reference it wont work.

Any ideas on how i could do it ?

Comment: It should be `&amp;` not just `&amp` ... though I feel the need to ask *why* you'd want to replace them if these URLs are embedded into HTML documents...

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use a simple `$message = str_replace('&amp', '&', $message);`? are there other `&amp` that you want to keep?

Comment: Yes there might be more escaped & and i dont want to change them

Comment: CD001's comment is relevant though, if the url is just displayed in html, you shouldn't have to remove them, and if it is planned to use the urls, it would be better not to `htmlspecialchars` on them as a start. We might miss a better solution by not knowing the entire goal here, but as a partial answer, you could use Wiktor Stribiżew's answer, with a htmlspecialchars_decode() in the callback to cope with all replacements

Answer (score 0):

You may match the URLs with a relatively simple `!https?://\S+!` (matching `http://` or `https://` and then matching 1+ non-whitespace symbols) and modify the `&amp` inside each match using a `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback('!https?://\S+!', function ($m) { 
    return str_replace('&amp', '&', $m[0]); 
}, $message);
```

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/RCxpkx).

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
preg_match_all('%https?://\S+%msi', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
{
    $fixed = preg_replace('/&amp/i', '&', $match);
    $match = preg_quote($match);
    $html = preg_replace("@$match@", $fixed, $html);
}
```